# Given a sequence of XML paths, generate the XML tree structure

Tags: xml, xpath, marklogic

I want to solve a problem - given an arbitrary sequence of xml paths, I want to generate the xml tree structure:

e.g. given this sequence:

```
"/person/name" "/person/address" "/person/age" "/person/parent/name"
```

generate:

```
<person>
<name></name>
<address></address>
<parent>
<name></name>
</parent>
</person>
```

Does anyone know of a good example of how to do this in xquery and/or XSLT?

Thanks

Comment: How do you provide input to xslt?

Answer (score 4):

This is a recursion problem. You want to process all the XPaths at once, but consume them step by step. At each step, identify the distinct elements that needs to be created, create them, and then within each, recursively call the same function on the tails of all the paths that go through that new element.

```
declare function local:generate($paths) {
    if(fn:empty($paths)) then () else

    let $heads := $paths ! fn:subsequence(fn:tokenize(.,'/'),1,1)
    let $tails := $paths ! fn:string-join(fn:subsequence(fn:tokenize(.,'/'),2),'/')

    for $element in fn:distinct-values($heads)
    return
        if($element='') then local:generate($tails)
        else element { xs:QName($element) } {
            let $nextPaths := for $tail at $n in $tails where fn:starts-with($paths[$n],$element||'/') return $tail
            return local:generate($nextPaths)
        }
};

local:generate(("/person/name", "/person/address", "/person/age", "/person/parent/name"))
```

Comment: The solution can be improved in 3.1 by using arrays - which allow nested sequences to be represented.

Comment: Thanks Ben, this works really well! I'll look at Michael's suggestion too.

Comment: Ben, your function works fine when I pass a string in as you have done. However when I try to pass in output from a function I have, which outputs a string in the same format

I get an error:
XDMP-CAST: (err:FORG0001) xs:QName($element) -- Invalid cast: "&quot;" cast as xs:QName

Why is not working when passing the string from my function when the same output works if I manually paste in that output as a string?

Comment: The error message means the function is trying to create an element with a name which is a quotation mark. I infer your function is creating a string The function is written to accept a sequence of strings, not a string which contains a sequence of strings.

Comment: i.e. ("/a/b", "/a/c"), not "'/a/b', '/a/c'"